How can we store a node's validator key for block validation in an HSM
When we build a Polygon Edge blockchain and create a node, we want to store the validator node key in an HSM or another secure location.
Could you provide any reference on how this can be done?
Is it possible to run the node in one VM while keeping the key in another location, where they can still communicate to validate blocks?
